# urls.py for the configuration of edx ora2(openassessment)

Tags: django, django-urls, edx

I would like to ask a question about django urls configuration of ORA2 xblock in open edx :

According to comments in filesystem.py, urls.py for openassessment.fileupload should be included in the urls.py of the app (lms):

openassessment/fileupload/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('openassessment.fileupload.views_filesystem',
    url(r'^(?P<key>.+)/$', 'filesystem_storage', name='openassessment-filesystem-storage'),
```

edx-platform/lms/urls.py:

```
...
urlpatterns = (
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'branding.views.index', name="root"),   # Main marketing page, or redirect to courseware
    url(r'', include('student.urls')),
...
    # URL for openassessment-fileupload  --by 
    url(r'^openassessment/storage', include(openassessment.fileupload.urls)),
)
```

During testing, the homepage reported "500 internal server error", and the error_log is:

```
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/lms/urls.py", line 124, in <module>
    url(r'^openassessment/storage', include(openassessment.fileupload.urls)),
NameError: name 'openassessment' is not defined
```

Also, I checked already the "openassessment.fileupload" is already included in settings.INSTALLED_APPS.

Could any one help me to check whether the url related codes are correct? Or there's other reason that cause the bug? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it seems simple but took me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found where's the problem. In below source codes, the quote of '' is missed in include().

```
...
urlpatterns = (
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'branding.views.index', name="root"),   # Main marketing page, or redirect to courseware
    url(r'', include('student.urls')),
...
    # URL for openassessment-fileupload  --by 
    url(r'^openassessment/storage', include(openassessment.fileupload.urls)),
)
```